# Querying a list of key value pair

Tags: c#, key-value

I have created a list of key value pair and am running a query to find if an id appers more than once in the list. The id is held in the "Value" part. I am using the following code but am not sure how to get the "Value" of the key value pair. See the end of the line:

```
var result = tableIds
     .GroupBy(v => v.Value)
     .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
     .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, ));
```

NB: tableIds looks like this:

```
var tableIds = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
```

I am basically wanting to find where an id in the "value" appears more than once. If it does, I need to store the key and value for use later. If the id appears in several places with a different key, i would need to capture all these.

Comment: Are you looking for duplicate Keys or duplicate Values? Your text and code seem to disagree.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking. Please concrete expected result and sense of your Key and Value in pair.

Comment: The `x` in your Select() is not a KVP but a Group item, it's an IEnumerable with an extra (group-)Key property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
tableIds.GroupBy(v => v.Key).Where(c => c.Count() > 1).SelectMany(c=> c).ToList()
```

It returns every KV pair that has other KV in tableId with same Key.

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thanks to everyone as I hadn't got my head round what was happening with the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

Besides that you are grouping on the value, not on the key, there is something else wrong: you expect a single value, while the grouped result has multiple values. Without joining them, you can't return an enumerable of `KeyValuePair<string, string>`.

If you just want to have any value, use `First()`:

```
 .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.First().Key));
```

Note that your `x.Key` in the lambda is actually `v.Value`. So the confusing double use of a `Key` is intentional. If your intention was to group on the key, use this:

```
var result = tableIds
     .GroupBy(v => v.Key)
     .Where(c => c.Count() > 1)
     .Select(x=> new KeyValuePair<string, string>(x.Key, x.First().Value));
```